# RSpec page variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

How is it that rspec feature tests implicitly know to use methods such as `find`, `within`, and `fill_in` from the page object?

I've written a helper class for some of my rspec tests and wanted to use those methods, and realized that I needed to pass the page object into the method, and then use `page.find` and the like.

Comment: Did my mean to say something other than "_page_ the page object into the method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec achieves this by including `Capybara::DSL` in those cases where it wants those methods available.    The module is pretty elegant, if you want to take a look at https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/f83edc2a515a3a4fd80eef090734d14de76580d3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb

Comment: So would there be a way for my helper to have access to the same page objects without having to pass it in?

Comment: As you said in your earlier comment, I believe it is indeed as simply as adding `include Capybara::DSL` to your helper.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to include the following module:

```
module MailerMacros
  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end
end
```

to include them, just call `config.include(MailerMacros)`, like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include(MailerMacros)
end
```

now, you should be able to call `reset_email()` & `last_email` instead of `MailerMacros::reset_email()`.